# ListView not displaying items correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

What i'm basically trying to do is, to make similar layout in C# Windows Form:

[image]

But I've tried like ten times with different codes but nothing seems to work. At last, i tried to create the same layout through the design view, I had my icons stored in a image list and the Image List was assigned to the List View. If i create a group named "BIOS", add a single item named "BIOS Type" and afterwards add a Sub Item "Insyde" ( see the image above ), only the group name is shown, the item and sub item is missing. I basically need to do this through coding, but it won't even work with design view.

My Code:

```
ListViewGroup group = new ListViewGroup("Computer", HorizontalAlignment.Left);
group.Header = "Computer Info";
listView.Groups.Add(group);
//= new ListViewItem(string name, int ImageIndex, ListViewGroup GroupName);
ListViewItem Item = new ListViewItem("Test", 3, group);
Item.Text = "Check";
listView.Items.Add(Item);
```

The View Property is set to "Details". This only displays the group header "Computer Info", no items .-.

I would be highly thankful if you anyone can help me with this, I'm stuck with this since 90 minutes -.-

Comment: I'd also post some code so people won't rewrite a full example when you may need to correct just one line!

Comment: Provide code you are working with

Comment: okay, I added the code I'm currently working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a 'View' property to a ListView that can be one of five different settings - make sure that is set to the 'Details' option. (For more information on the different options click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.view%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

You will also need an ImageList if you don't have one already - add images to it and then add it as the SmallImageList property of the ListView to be able to assign items images.
The first column will be the text for your item. For the remaining columns you will need sub-items for each item - in the order that you want them displayed.

In order to show sub items you will need to ensure that there are enough columns in the columns collection to show all of them - one for the title and image of each item and then one each for the sub-items.

Sorry if you knew some of this already, just trying to cover any possible issues you may have. Hope this helps.

Comment: @HumzaKhan : Alpar's hints are spot on. Your code does not create the necessary 2nd column: listView.Columns.Add("Insyde"); now you can add a subitem: Item.SubItems.Add("Insyde"); Note: The naming scheme is off with ListView: Items-SubItems-Columns. Other than that it all works fine.

Comment: Yes, it works now. It was the columns. Thank you everyone ^_^